# Append java.library.path in command line

Tags: java, command-line, executable-jar

```
-Djava.library.path="path to a dll"
```

This replace the environment path variable in the current session. I want to append this path to the already existing path.

Kindly let me know how to do it. I'm calling a jar from command prompt using

```
java -Djava.library.path="path to a dll" -jar myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `-Djava.library.path="%PATH%;path to a dll"` or if it does't work
you need to get existing PATH variable value and add you path to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. On Windows: Add the path to the library to the PATH environment variable.
2. On Linux: Add the path to the library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
3. On Mac: Add the path to the library to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

`java.library.path` is initilized with the values of the variables above on its corresponding platform.

You can test if the value is what you expect by calling `java -XshowSettings:properties`